# How to manage one Session Per Tab?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-cookies

Hi I will like to imitate the behaviour of the site ClickBank.com, for example:

Open the site, and login, if i open a tab with the same site, it ask me again to login.

It makes me wonder how to manage one session per tab.

Just to clarify, i don't loose control on the first tab if i log on in the new tab. They are separate sessions.

Thank you

Comment: Just some wild guessing: If you pass the session ID in the URL (cookieless sessions), You could have different session IDs in different tabs.

Comment: Yes but that's kind of dangerous because the session id is visible. Anyway i tried and it didn't worked

Comment: did you found solution for this? i am looking for it as well.

Comment: Did you try this on your web.config? (From MSDN)

`<configuration>
`  <system.web>
`    <sessionState cookieless="true" '    `regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
`  </system.web>
`</configuration>

Answer (score 2):

Create a hidden field with a page ID and include that when you are trying to access whatever object in session Assign a random guid or value to that hidden control and then use it to store stuff in session

ex.

Session(PageID.Value & "CheckBoxes") = D

Hope that help!

[asp.net - session - multiple browser tabs - different sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions)

Comment: what is "CheckBoxes" here? session name??

Comment: Session["CheckBoxes"] ??