# Session ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

Session question in asp.net/c#

I have multiple asp.net pages and a class object.
e.g. 
Class User object contains

```
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Address { set; get; }
    etc.....
```

pg1.aspx: when button is clicked, the data is stored in the session and redirects to pg2.aspx

e.g. pg1.aspx

```
    User u = new User();
    u.Name = TextBox1.Text;
    Session.Add("USERINFO", u);
    Response.Redirect("pg2.aspx");
```

e.g. pg2.aspx //reading the data..

```
    User u = ((User)Session["USERINFO"]);
    Response.Write(u.Name + "<br/>");
```

..etc.. ( I have 5 pages and the data is passed around from page to page in a session) once the user reaches the last page it stores in the database otherwise I dont want to store incomplete data in the database.

It all works fine except if I use multiple tabs to run same web app, the data overwrites eachother... It works fine if I use separate browsers, but not with tabs...

How can I avoid a user to enter the data in tab1 get to page 3 and if the user opens tab2 and continues not to over the data was entered in tab1....

I hope it makes sense... what I am trying to accomplish... Thank you.

Comment: Try and make your question summary more descriptive than Session ASP.net

Comment: So what you are saying is on the redirect if the user has things configured to open new windows in a tab then your application doesn't work?

Comment: Might find this useful: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/04/17/asp.net-session-state-shared-between-ie-tabs-and-ie8.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a duplicate question, so I'll simply redirect you to some answers that would solve your problem.

- [asp.net - session - multiple browser tabs - different sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions)

Unfortunately, the accepted answer won't work since it maintains a "unique" session identifier for each page, not your group of 5 pages.

Your browser version and the different methods of launching new tabs and windows in it determines whether sessions are shared across multiple tabs and windows. Controlling it could be done with

- The modification to web.config as described in the linked article
- Coming up with a unique session key prefix for each session value
- Using some logic to prevent the same user from opening multiple sessions on the same machine

Comment: The question is not very clear but I'll try to infer.  Before using sessions you should understand how they work.

Sessions (by default) rely on "Session Cookies" which (by default) are generated when the session is initialized and are shared between tabs.

This article from Microsoft (from the above referenced answer) provides more detail.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: @kingdango: thanks for helping to clarify what I was trying to say!

Comment: Sorry for not been clear enough, I need to keep track multiple sessions if multiple tabs are been used. Cory I tried using the link you posted but I am not sure what i need to do after I generate the pogeId and save it to the user object... how do I not overwrite the data if another tab is been used? If I add the    
      <sessionState cookieless="true"    
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" /> it works but it shows the session id in the browser, how do i not show it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to work around your current implementation would likely be to check whether or not you have the information you would expect from that page, and if the conditions aren't met then require the data to be input, or redirect appropriately depending on which stage in the process you are (based on the data that *is* available).

So, as well as adding to the session, you can get:

```
var value = Session[key] as string;
if (value != null)
{
    //move on to the next appropriate page 
    //after determining which that is by other conditions
}
//we obviously need the page at which we get this data!
```

And you can build upon your conditions from there

Comment: I canot do that because the user can go back to the previous page and modify the data.