# How to manage authentication and session, when i use my silverlight app in multiple browser tabs

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, authentication, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I´ve noticed that my Silverlight/WCF RIA Services application overrides local browser login/session, when i use my silverlight application in multiple tabs or multiple instances of a browser.

> When i open my application in one Tab (Tab 1) and log in as
>   "Systemadminstrator" (aka. getting access to all operations) and open
>   an other Tab (Tab 2) to log in as "Default User" (aka. restricted
>   access to operations), then i don´t have access to operations of
>   "Systemadministrator" in Tab 1. I get the message "**Access to
>   operation 'xyz' denied**".

I can reproduce this behavior and it isn´t browser specific. So how can i manage multiple logins to my application in a browser? Do i have to edit or extend the data that is stored in the cookie?

**Background:**
My DomainServices are decorated with the RequiresAuthenticationAttribute and some methods on the domain services require a specific role set via RequiresRoleAttribute. I have a custom AuthenticationService and RoleProvider. Using only one Tab is no problem.

**Update:**
I tried the solution provided in the question [asp.net - session - multiple browser tabs - different sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions) setting following values in the configuration file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The Urls in the 2 Tabs contain diffrent session ids but the effect is the same.

Comment: You are sitting on top of a ASP.NET session. I believe that this question/answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions

Comment: @Rus : Not bad. This seems to answer my question. I will give it a try and comeback.

Comment: @Rus: I tried the second answer of the question, but this doesn´t change the bevahior.