# Accessing control from a master page asp.net - storing the value

Tags: asp.net, session, static, master-pages, viewstate

At the moment I have a master page and a content page. My master page consists of a dropdownlist, from which I need to select a child from. The content page loads according the child chosen. How should I store the dropdownvalue chosen?

I don't think I can use the **session**, since I would like the user to be able to open multiple tabs and watch different children contents at the same time. If I can use the session in this case, I'm not sure how.

I don't think I can use the **viewstate** since, although it solves my multiple tabs problem, the master page and content page have a different view state.

At the moment I am using a public **static** variable on the content page, and I set it in the master page. But from what I've heard static variables have their values stored throughout ALL the current sessions on the site.

**Question:**
Can any one help me by suggesting which technology should I use?

I have also heard about the 'Application' object but I don't think it makes sense to use it.

**Current working Code:**

(content page)

```
public static string Child
    {
        get
        {
            if (child == null)
                return "-1";
            return child;
        }

        set
        {
            child = value;
        }
    }
```

(master page)

```
protected void ddlChooseChild_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ContentPage.Child = ddlChooseChild.SelectedValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to share data between different controls is to make use of the "Items" collection (which is a property of the [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) class). The collection is a Hashtable and can be accessed from your Page and User Controls like so:

```
Context.Items["Child"] = ddlChooseChild.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! Solved it perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are restricting session by using [PageID or something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions) similar, Sessions are available on multiple tabs.

Check out this article, [Master Content Page interaction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36055/Interaction-Between-Content-Page-and-Master-Page)

Comment: I know the session is available on multiple tabs, but I want the SAME session variable to have different values on different tabs. Is this possible with session?

Comment: @test, something like this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions

Comment: @test You can store an object in your session variable.  Your object may contain whatever information you want any any number of tabs using lists, arrays, etc.