# ASP.NET - Session variables and Overlapped recycle

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

What is an overlapped recycle as described on the following webpage in the second to last paragraph: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

I have a problem with session variables at the moment.  It appears that in one isolated case they were shared across two pages on one client.  I am trying to establish whether an overlapped recycle or multi instancing could be the cause.  I am using standard ASP.NET cookies.

I have Googled the two terms but I could only find an explanation in the context of Sharepoint server.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when one gets session variables being shared between client instances it is because a "web garden" is being used and the session state is held in-process.

In that case, you need to use an out-of-process state server; there's more explanation at [ASP.NET: Moving Session Out-of-Process with StateServer](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/aspnet-moving-session-out-of-process.html), and the documentation is at [Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If your state server is on the same machine, the web.config entry would look something like `<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="40" />`.

On the other hand, if the same session state is being used in two tabs in a browser, then this looks like a useful solution: [asp.net - session - multiple browser tabs - different sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  I am not sure how this answers my question though.  Do you know what is meant by an overlapped recycle?