# Need help understanding sessions and user profile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently planning my web application. I was thinking using Session to store user profile (user name, current database, permissions, etc...). Common scenario is where user opens several tabs for different pages.

Now, I need to have an option for user to change the database. Basically needs to choose the database from list, enter a log in information and it's done. Not sure how to handle this. It seems that browser tab where user initiated the change should somehow tell server that he needs a new session here or server has to inform browser that new session is generated?

Basically if user has 4 tabs open and initiates a database change on one tab then he should end up with two sessions? Is this correct or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: For reference, might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am getting your problem, one thing can be done that whenever the user selects a new database and enters the log-in information then on selecting the new database, you need to clear out the old session details for the database and on entering the new session for login information, override the login details.

Also, store the old information into another session and whenever a conflict occurs you can navigate to the error page saying that "Login information and databse have been changed" or any custom message.

Only work around needs to be thought of for this scenario as in same browser the session value will be same throughout.