# How to make a Multi Login User Using ASP.Net MVC 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to make a multi user login for my application. In this multiple user can login in different tabs of same browser.

Comment: Maybe, you can use sessionStorage https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp 
You keep session info on the browser session

Comment: You can use Session **createSessionKey** for each user
check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722171/asp-net-multiple-session-objects-in-a-single-application

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i am using owin library for login system, it is Single SO. I want to make it multi sign on

Answer (score 0):

you need to maintain unique session for each login you can check this 
[Unique session in multiple browser tabs in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816576/unique-session-in-multiple-browser-tabs-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i am using owin library for login system, it is Single SO. I want to make it multi sign on.