# Implementing the Notification from WhatsApp desktop to a ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, whatsapp

I'm currently working in a ASP.NET web application. Recently I got a requirement that is like the notification you get from WhatsApp web. This is if you are logged in a tab and you enter again to WhatsApp web in the same browser you get this notification:

WhatsApp is open in another window. Click "Use Here" to use WhatsApp in this window.

So I was wondering is it possible to implement this functionality in a ASP.NET application.

Comment: You will get the idea from following link if you want to implement such kind of functionality : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions

Comment: I saw the post but i don't think it will work cause currently I´m using MVC.I saw a response that the solution proposed wouldnt work with this type of project. Thank you for the reply anyways