# Using ASP.NET, how can I force IIS 7 to give me two concurrent session IDs from the same computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session, iis

I have an application that uses APS.NET as the middle tier. One of the features for administrators is to allow them to popup another browser window logged in as a non-admin user, so they can provide support.

I use a javascript function "openWindowWithPost." The application takes credentials from a DB and forces a login so the support staff does not need to know the user credentials. Unfortunately when it does that the original session is reused and hence all of their application variables are shared, causing havoc with the original Admin login.

What I would like the ability to do is to force a second browser window to popup and when it talks to IIS have it create a new session and keep the original one active. Is this possible? If so where can I find how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net - session - multiple browser tabs - different sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it looks like you are using the Session object in ASP.Net to store data.

By default the Session ID is stored by the browser in a cookie.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
for a description of how it works.  You could setup your application to use query strings to store the session id, but that is really old fashion and can become messy and hard to deal with.

Your best bet is to find a solution at the browser level.  For example, Firefox has an extension called [Multifox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multifox/) that would do what you want.  Other browsers have similar extensions.