# Prevent input boxes from being linked across browser tabs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

So I have an ASP.NET website using C#. When I open the same page on two different browser tabs the input boxes (ASP.NET TextBox Controls) are synced in that when I type something in one it also appears in the other input box on the other tab.

Short of programmatically changing the ID individually or the content place holder ID at page load and setting ClientIDMode to static, how can I break the link? I've tried using different sessions via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840615/asp-net-session-multiple-browser-tabs-different-sessions) with no luck.

The pages will typically be differentiated by query strings but the controls have to be unique across browser tabs.

Sample Textbox Control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="BoxTitle" runat="server" onkeyup="CharCount(this.id, 50);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code you have used for this control? Typically text boxes are not linked unless you have used some specific library/tool to keep them in sync.

Comment: Updated, it's like this all across the site, every input/textbox.

Comment: Are you saying the text appears immediately on the other tab?  Or does it appear when you refresh the page?

Comment: Immediately, as in they are in sync. I just tried creating a brand new website to test with and it does the same thing, tried multiple browsers too.

Comment: It also syncs across separate browser windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, the solution was browser link in visual studio had "Enable Browser Sync" turned on which was the issue.

See more here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserSync